# Sass Class Inheritance:

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Using Sass, and Compass I would like to import one font file, but have 3 different sizes for it.  But this question is more basic than that,  The following code is an example of how I think maybe, but not sure sass class inheritance can work. what would be the best practice for something like this?

Something like

```
@include font-face("Kingthings Kelltika",font-files("http://www.fontsaddict.com/fontface/kingthings-kelltika.ttf"));
.Kingthings {
    font-family:"Kingthings Kelltika";
    .small{
            font-size:.7em;
     }
.medium{
            font-size:.1em;
     }
.large{
            font-size:2em;
     }
}
```

and then in the html say something like

```
<div class= "Kingthings small">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors will never be reached how you have defined them:

Here is an easy way to do what you are looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/twT2e/

```
<div class= "Arial font-lg">
    Sample Text
</div>

.Arial   { font-family:"Arial"; }
.font-sm { font-size:.7em; }
.font-md { font-size:1em; }
.font-lg { font-size:2em;  }
```

If you want to use SASS to provide some sort of hierarchy to your selectors it would look something like this;

```
<div class= "Arial">
    <div class="font-sm">Sample Text1</div>
    <div class="font-md">Sample Text1</div>
    <div class="font-lg">Sample Text1</div>
</div>  

.Arial   { font-family:"Arial"; 
    .font-sm { font-size:.7em; }
    .font-md { font-size:1em; }
    .font-lg { font-size:2em;  }
}
```